# Svn Synchronize in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Am just move to Android Studio (I/O Preview) 0.2.0 from Eclipse. But the SVN plugin in Android Studio is quite hard to understand for me, I was trying to synchronize from repository to see the changes made by other developers like we doing in Eclipse but unfortunately I am struck to find such things in Android studio. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for the solution. Use the 'Changes' view in Android studio. You can see local/Repository/Incoming files which is similar to eclipse svn synchronize

For more details refer, http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.0.1:

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Version Control (Alt + 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

right click your project and select the

`Subversion` -> in that choose the `Update Directory...`

Comment: but this will directly update the local directories with out showing a synchronized view as in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project app folder and click subversion > commit Directory  and you will get the commit changes window where in you can see all the files which are changed which is equivalent to svn synchronize in eclipse.